# PySpark: GroupBy with max date does'nt work properly (TypeError: Column is not iterable)

Tags: pyspark, max

With Pyspark, I want all lines with the same name and id and max(date). So I do:

```
temp_df = df.select("year", "month", "tfh", "tfc", "name", "id")\
    .withColumn("date", concat(col("year"), lit("-"), col("month")))\
    .withColumn("date", col("date").cast("date"))\
    .groupBy("name", "id", "tfh", "tfc").agg(max("date").alias("date"))
```

and I get something like that:

```
+------+------+----+----+----------+
|id    |name  |tfh |tfc |date      |
+------+------+----+----+----------+
|1     | test | 16 | 34 |2018-09-01|
|2     | test | 56 | 22 |2018-03-01|
|3     | test | 11 | 12 |2019-01-01|
|4     | test | 45 | 67 |2018-01-01|
|5     | test | 23 | 76 |2018-09-01|
+------+------+----+----+----------+
```

As tfh and tfc are different, I have not got only one row with the max date for the same id and name.
So I decided to change the strategy by doing `.groupBy("name", "id").agg(max("date").alias("date"))` and join this dataset with the parent one like that

```
temp_df = temp_df.join(tfh_tfc_df, ["id", year(temp_df.date) == tfh_tfc_df.year, month(temp_df.date) == tfh_tfc_df.month, "name"], "left")
```

But I always have the error `TypeError: Column is not iterable`
I tried with solution found on internet with `exp(  ).alias()` but nothing works.

The result I expect to find for each combination of id/name is:

```
+------+------+----+----+----------+
|id    |name  |tfh |tfc |date      |
+------+------+----+----+----------+
|3     | test | 11 | 12 |2019-01-01|
+------+------+----+----+----------+
```

Could you help me? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`window`** functions for this case.

- `partitionBy` on `name,id` column
- get the `max` from the window

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'test', 16,34,'2018-09-01'),(2, 'test', 56,22,'2018-03-01'),(3, 'test', 11,12,'2019-01-01'),(4, 'test', 45,67,'2018-01-01'),(5, 'test', 23,76,'2018-09-01')], ['id','name','tfh','tfc','date'])
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *

w = Window.partitionBy("name","id")

df = df.withColumn("max_date",max(col("date")).over(w))

df.show(10,False)
#+---+----+---+---+----------+----------+
#|id |name|tfh|tfc|date      |max_date  |
#+---+----+---+---+----------+----------+
#|1  |test|16 |34 |2018-09-01|2018-09-01|
#|2  |test|56 |22 |2018-03-01|2018-03-01|
#|3  |test|11 |12 |2019-01-01|2019-01-01|
#|4  |test|45 |67 |2018-01-01|2018-01-01|
#|5  |test|23 |76 |2018-09-01|2018-09-01|
#+---+----+---+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that doesn't change anything. I edited my answer to show what I want as final result